# How to add checkbox in the bottom left corner of QGraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qcheckbox, qstyle

I want to add a checkbox in the left corner of  `QGraphicsView` .

I tried painting it directly in `painEvent` of my view .

```
void BhGraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);
    QStyleOptionButton opt;
    opt.state = QStyle::State_Active | QStyle::State_Enabled;
    opt.rect = QRect(x,y,300,300);
    QPainter painter(viewport());
    //histogram_cbox_ is a QCheckBox
    histogram_cbox_->style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_CheckBox, &opt, &painter);
  // ....
 }
```

I didn't find QStyleOptionCheckBox so I used `QStyleOptionButton` .

But the problem is it doesn't show the text of the `QCheckbox` .

How can I draw a  clickable checkbox on a `QGraphicsView` ?!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `QCheckBox` to the  `QGraphicsView` in a layout :

```
QCheckBox * checkBox = new QCheckBox();
QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout(ui->myView);
layout->addWidget(checkBox,0,0,0,0,Qt::AlignBottom | Qt::AlignLeft);
```

Comment: I want to put the checkbox on the view not bellow it .  My code add the checkbox but it doesn't draw the text of  check box http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=v5l7au&s=8#.U4eRVvmSzhY

Comment: This will put the checkbox on the view. You can also put the above code in the constructor of your custom view and replace `ui->myView` with `this`.